# Site not responding error - taking long to load

Tags: mysql, server-load

I have a wordpress website which gets around 20K visits a days and with around 7pages/visit and 62 hits per visit.

My server is :

> 8 processors --> Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5405 @ 2.00GHz
>
> 8 GB RAM

Now my users are complaining about that the site takes time to load sometimes and craches giving the taking too long to load and it also happened to me a couple of times wher i thought it was my connection.

From previous issues I know that there is a query that sometimes take too long and the site was crashing from it. I then tweaked the server and changed the query_cach_size (because on days with traffic spike the site was stopping alot) in the `my.cnf` file into `256MB` and after that the site stopped the errors on busy days but started giving this kind of error.

Any ideas ? How can I monitor my site and see when it goes down and what is causing it to troubleshoot this ?

---

**EDIT:**

1. I am using a dedicated server.
2. The `my.cnf` file looks like:

   ```
   [mysqld]
   max_connections = 250
   safe-show-database
   skip-locking
   key_buffer = 128M
   max_allowed_packet = 24M
   table_cache = 700
   sort_buffer_size = 16M
   read_buffer_size = 8M
   read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
   myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
   query_cache_size = 128M
   max_heap_table_size = 180M
   tmp_table_size = 180M
   thread_cache_size = 16
   wait_timeout = 45
   interactive_timeout = 600
   skip-name-resolve
   skip-innodb

   [mysqldump]
   quick
   max_allowed_packet = 16M

   [mysql]
   no-auto-rehash

   [isamchk]
   key_buffer = 80M
   sort_buffer_size = 64M
   read_buffer = 2M
   write_buffer = 2M

   [myisamchk]
   key_buffer = 80M
   sort_buffer_size = 64M
   read_buffer = 2M
   write_buffer = 2M
   ```
3. The site will stop responding sometime when I click on any hyperlink (post, page just anything that requires action).

Thank you

Comment: I feel the Q is off topic. But: Can you extend your Q (edit) with what you´re using for caching, minify, etc.? Also: VPS, shared host (I guess first?) and some in depth about your queries. On which page is it stopping (if you can hunt that one down) and what´s the exact query? There´s a debug plugin and a query extension that could be useful (search repo).

Comment: thnx, I have added some more info.

Comment: n/p. Please click the `edit` link to see how you can format a question for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be blindly changing configs in my.cnf.

Use [rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl · GitHub](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl) to test and check your my.cnf configs. It will give suggestions for memory allocations and all other aspects of MySQL tuning.

You also should configure httpd.conf for high loads. See [Apache Performance Tuning - Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/perf-tuning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
thread_cache_size=250
```

Let me know how it goes.  Thanks

Comment: @momo Have you tried these suggestions in your my.cnf [mysqld] section? Would require stop/start to become effective, unless you know how to SET GLOBAL variable-name=value; for these Dynamic variables.